# Timeout Errors with Redis on Scaling Node.js Application Pods in EKS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, redis

I'm running a Node.js application on Amazon EKS that connects to an Amazon Elastic Cache Redis instance (Node type: cache.t3.micro) configured as a single-node cluster. The security rules are properly configured, and the application can successfully connect to Redis when running a small number of pods (between 4 and 10). However, when scaling the application to 20-30 pods, I start encountering timeout errors on Redis connections.

**Here's the snippet of code used for establishing the Redis connection in my Node.js application:**

```
const redisClient = require("redis");

const initRedisClient = async () => {
    try {
        info(`connecting to redis client`);
        let connectionClient = redisClient.createClient({
            url : `redis://${redisUrl}:6379`
        });
        connectionClient.on("error",(err) => {
            console.log("error",err);
            throw new Error(err?.message);
        });
        connectionClient.on("connect",function () {
            console.log("redis connected successfully!");
            // storeData("WAIT_TIME","5",false,0);
            // storeData("BUFFER_TIME","2",false,0); 
        })
        await connectionClient.connect();
        client = connectionClient;
        return client;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error?.message);
        console.log(error?.message);
        return {
            type : "error",
            message : error?.message
        };
    }
}
```

#### Environment Details:

- Node.js version: 14.x
- Redis client library/version: Redis 4.1.0
  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)
- Node type for Elastic Cache Redis: cache.t3.micro (Engine version: 7.1.0)
- Cluster configuration: Single-node cluster

**The error message received is related to connection timeouts. However, there's no issue with the initial connection or with a lower number of pods.**

#### What I've Tried:

- Verified security rules and network connectivity which all seem correctly configured.
- Ensured the Redis instance is operational and accessible from an individual pod.

**Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.**